# Touchable Opacity onPress not able to call function - scoping issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scope

I'm developing in React Native.

I have a `FlatList` that renders items. I have added `TouchableOpacity` and would like to call a function upon press of that item, but the function is not being called.

When I click on the item I get an error of ***cannot find variable: _onPress***

I think it's an issue with scoping. Would someone be able to explain to me what is going wrong please?

I guess a secondary question is: will my `_onPress` console.log the item name by passing the prop in like I have?

```
export default class ModalScreen extends React.Component {
//..

        _onPress = (item) => {
           console.log('Clicked:' + item)
        };

      renderItem({ item }) {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPress(item)}>
            <View>
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      }



render() {  
    return (
    //..
          <View style={{flex: 2, backgroundColor: '#FFF', flexDirection:'row'}} >
                <FlatList
                data={this.state.searchedItems}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                />
            </View>

    //..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change this 'renderItem({ item }) {' with this 'renderItem = ({ item }) => {

Comment: Legend! Thank you. Can you explain what was going on there? As in what difference that makes?

Only thing it doesn't do is take in the item prop and console.log it. Currently it logs 'Clicked undefined'. Can you help there?

Comment: It's because when you provide your renderItem function the scope change so inside renderItem function this refer to the TouchableOpacity instance

Comment: But how does adding the arrow function help? What does the arrow function do that is different. Apologies, I need to get up to speed with arrow functions etc.

Comment: Arrow function dont have this scope, when you declare function in the class with arrow function this will always refer to the current instance of the class